# How to connect an API to a app made from flutter?

Tags: android, ios, api, flutter, dart

I am currently working on a app for both iOS and android through flutter. My app is functioning properly, but I need to connect an ad api to it.
I appreciate your help and time for reading this! Just saying this is my secondary account and I am not new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add [HTTP package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and follow the rules